# Texturing and importing to unity

Tags: mesh, texturing, unity

I texture a model and then import it to unity. The texture doesn't stay, Why is this and is there a way to get a textured UV map?

Comment: you dont put a texture on a model, you put it on the material. you either did not unwrap the mesh or your material name is something that already exists in your unity project. thought i cant see any pictures so

Comment: first are you using cycles? second are you really using an image texture?